# Flow to create a UID and email this uid to a staff member

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have been trying to create a flow that will create a UID and then email this to a staff member in a fully automatted process.

I am using the rand function to create the UID.

[image: My Flow]

This part is working fine but it falls over when trying to the send the email as the UID part is blank.

Does anyone know a way round this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a similar sample flow and works fine. Does the list item UID field successfully updated by the flow? If so, please check the email settings in flow. Make sure your are using the UID dynamic content in the update list item Action.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go.